# VBScript: Assigning an array(2) via createobject

Tags: vb6, vbscript, exchangewebservices

I'm having a problem converting this VB6 code to VBScript. I'm calling out to a COM object to create an array as EmailAddressType. Here is the working VB6 Code:

```
'Assign TO: addresses
Dim toAdresses(2) As New EmailAddressType
toAdresses(0).EmailAddress = "someone@whocares.com"
toAdresses(0).RoutingType = "SMTP"
toAdresses(1).EmailAddress = "someoneelse@whocares.com"
toAdresses(1).RoutingType = "SMTP"
email.ToRecipients = toAdresses
```

I can't seem to figure out how to convert this into VBScript. I've tried the following but just get a Type Mismatch error once I get to the email.ToRecipients = toAdresses

```
  'Assign TO: addresses
   dim toAdresses(2)
   set toAdresses(0) = createobject("EWS.EWSWebSvc.EmailAddressType")
   set toAdresses(1) = createobject("EWS.EWSWebSvc.EmailAddressType")
    toAdresses(0).EmailAddress = "someone@whocares.com"
    toAdresses(0).RoutingType = "SMTP"
    toAdresses(1).EmailAddress = "someoneelse@whocares.com"
    toAdresses(1).RoutingType = "SMTP"
    email.ToRecipients = toAdresses
```

Btw this is a COM wrapper of the Exchange Web Services if that helps any.

Comment: It probably won't work, but have you tried `Set email.ToRecipients = toAdresses`?

Comment: What type of object is `email`? In my experience, arrays in COM objects are different from arrays in VBScript so it is not possible to pass an array with objects from VBScript to the COM. If you can get in the code for the `email` object, you could make a method `AddRecipient(EmailAddressType emailAddress)` and add the recipients one by one through this interface or in a loop by collecting them in an array and then `For Each`ing them.

Comment: It's not been mentioned by anyone else yet, but you're creating an empty item at index 2. `Dim toAdresses(2)` defaults to 0 to 2, resulting in 3 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the .ToRecipients property wants an *array of EmailAddressType* while all you can easily get in VBScript is a Variant or array of Variants.

Looks like this API was just not built to be scriptable.

Oddly enough there is an implication it can be used from JScript though: [MessageType.ToRecipients Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.messagetype.torecipients%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

I suspect they are rewriting history by gradually editing out any mention of VBScript on MSDN these days though.

Comment: After long research I've found out that IEnumarables cannot be marshaled from a COM to VBScript. Works fine in VB6 though.

Comment: Maybe the example on the MSDN page is in [JScript.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET)? Seems like they've dropped the ".NET": [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a.aspx)

Comment: Excellent point.  I gnawed that over myself reading the item.  For all I know it might refer to the "new JScript" baked inside newer IE releases too but .Net seems more plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, try this

```
toAdresses.EmailAddress = "someone@whocares.com;someoneelse@whocares.com"
toAdresses.RoutingType = "SMTP"
email.ToRecipients = toAdresses
```

if it doesn't work with the ; try the ,